# Call function for other class/swiftfile in the same project

Tags: swift, function

I made the function :

```
func GetCurrentIndex (Table: Int) -> String {
```

in the class Index.

Now I want to call that function from the class GetTable using :

```
var index : Index!

let I = index.GetCurrentIndex(0)
```

What it does though is it retuns that nill was returned in an unexpected area and just crashes.

Comment: Did it say “unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”? If so, you never set a value to `index`

Comment: 1. Use lower case for function, argument, and variable names.  2. Don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals (there are exceptions, but assume they're aren't any and you'll figure it out).  3. Including all the code goes a long way toward getting a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function is not a class function and `Index` is not a class instance you should either:

define index as

```
var index = Index()
```

Making a class instance of index

or

```
class func  GetCurrentIndex (Table: Int) -> String {
```

This will make the function run on the class instead of an instance of the class.

Comment: `var index : Index()` isn't valid Swift.

Comment: @nhgrif thank you that should indeed and obviously have been an `=`

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you should declare your class and function public to allow access from another class.

```
public class Index {
    public func getCurrentIndex () {
        //code here
    }
}
```

And then from the class you wish to call it from, initialise index as follows:

```
var index : Index = Index()
```

Then you can call:

```
index.getCurrentIndex()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He already has most of this.  And you're skimming over the part he's got wrong.

Comment: However, the code above will work correctly, the way that he intends it to work.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood the question, in which case I shall edit my answer. I appreciate the quick edit also, was in a bit of a rush but trying to offer a working answer.

Comment: A good answer consists of more than simply a code dump which inexplicably solves the problem.

Comment: As you said, he wasn't far off and therefore I gathered it would easy enough to see where the differences lie and understand why. Not sure that this question requires an essay length explanation but next time I will attempt to provide more of an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your code compiles correctly tells us that your method is properly implemented<sup>1</sup>.  If your `instance` variable was of a type that the compiler did not know for sure had the `GetCurrentIndex` method as an instance method, your code would not have compiled.

What's happening is a complete failure to understand optionals and nil values.

As a start, we shouldn't use implicitly unwrapped optionals (what you've done when you typed `Index!`).  These allow you to write unsafe code and don't allow the compiler to enforce nil-checking.

If we instead declare our `index` variable as a regular optional (`Index?`), the compiler is going to force us to use some syntax that protects against the very real nil possibility:

```
var index: Index?

let i = index?.getCurrentIndex(0)
```

See the `?.` syntax?  That's called optional chaining.  What this syntax means is that **if** `index` is non-nil, we will call `getCurrentIndex(0)` on it and return the result.  Otherwise, we will simply return `nil`.  What we'll find (and you can see by holding Option and clicking on `i`) is that this makes `i`'s type also optional (`String?`).  The compiler can infer this because we have optionally chained on `index` and can know that `nil` is a valid possibility.  Additionally, the compiler knows that the method being called has a return type of `String`.

Now `i` will be of `String?` type, and we will do similar optional binding things to get its value out.

Alternatively, if we don't want optionals, then let's not make optionals, and do as the other answers have suggested and simply instantiate our `Index` object:

```
var index = Index()

let i = index.getCurrentIndex(0)
```

At the end of the day, the point is not to use implicitly unwrapped optionals (`Index!`) because they just lead to crashes.  Either make things non-optional and know that it's never nil, or make them fully optional and require explicit unwrapping code that the compiler will help you enforce.

---

<sup>1: In so much as, the problem is not with the method signature.  There very well could be a problem with the method body, but that's not part of this question.</sup>